# Cakephp 3 multiple custom template formhelpers

Tags: templates, cakephp, formhelper, cakephp-3.0

So I'm at work (working with sensitive data might I add for posterity's sake), and the powers that be decide we need to use the all powerful and least documented new tool by Cakephp 3.0 (beta at this time).

Edit: My goal is to create several different templates for forms to call through the formhelper template or input methods. There really isn't much of an a good example for this.
Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses:
As seen in the book(and nowhere else on the internet anywhere) the very short documentation is thus:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses

The site says you can use the template method and then give a vague "use":

```
$myTemplates = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
];
```

$this->Form->templates($myTemplates);

Then it says you can use the input() method for which it gives no example. 
And last but not least the custom template FormHelper should allow you to "make" or "create" as many of these custom formhelpers as you wish, but they give no example use of how to do that!? lulwut?

I can easily use it once like their example, but where's the power in a single custom template? That doesn't do me anygood.

So by a new possible solution I try and get a new error.

I get this error(within my view)(from the following code):

Fatal Error
Error: Class 'Configure' not found

```
//within bootstrap.php
Configure::write('templates', [
    'shortForm' => [
        'formstart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
        'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
        'input' => '<div class="col-md-4"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
        'select' => '<div class="col-md-4"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>    </div>',
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}    </div>',
        'checkContainer' => '',],
    'longForm' => [
        'formstart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
        'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
        'input' => '<div class="col-md-6"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
        'select' => '<div class="col-md-6"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>    </div>',
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}    </div>',
        'checkContainer' => '',],
    'fullForm' => [
        'formstart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
        'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
        'input' => '<div class="col-md-10"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} />    </div>',
        'select' => '<div class="col-md-10"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select>    </div>',
        'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}    </div>',
        'checkContainer' => '',]
]);

//within my view
<?php
    $this->Form->templates(Configure::read('templates.shortForm')); 
?>
```

**Old Update**: I added

```
use "Cake\Core\Configure;"
```

in my view and everything works great, but I would like to add this to the appropriate file in the hierarchy so that I don't have to add that to every view,

that is unless of course it causes efficacy issues for the entire app as a whole. Does anyone know which file it should go in? Regards and TIA!

**Newest Update**: I just figured it out. So simple! check my answer below! Hope this helped someone

Comment: So what do you want? This just sounds like a pretty long complaint but doesn't even tell us what your goal is? Also, if you read the documentation carefully, this is not about a single template but you can customize any output using the templates() method by passing a set of templates.

Comment: As I said, yes I agree that this is what the documentation says as it is obvious. My problem is that... how? how do you create these templates. They don't even create any templates in the example they give. They simply give a single stock default as the example. If I want to create three or four separate custom templates, how is this done? I found a site: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/08/11/twitter-bootstrap-forms-cakephp-3/ He does a similar thing, but explains that because of the lack of documentation he chooses to create custom widgets as custom template input forms through FormHelper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What this fix does is allow you to have custom template forms (from cakephp 3!!!!) using bootstrap. If you want to set sizes using the form helper and all of it's goodness (security and what not).

Jose Zap of Cakephp explained that the best option might be try a premade bootstrap plugins or widgets, but the real solution I've come up with is better as it doesn't require third party intevention:

Step 1: Create config/templatesConfig.php and add your custom form stuff.

```
<?php
$config = [
    'Templates'=>[
        'shortForm' => [
            'formStart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
            'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
            'input' => '<div class="col-md-4"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
            'select' => '<div class="col-md-4"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div>',
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}</div>',
            'checkContainer' => '',],
        'longForm' => [
            'formStart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
            'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
            'input' => '<div class="col-md-6"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
            'select' => '<div class="col-md-6"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div>',
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}</div>',
            'checkContainer' => '',],
        'fullForm' => [
            'formStart' => '<form class="" {{attrs}}>',
            'label' => '<label class="col-md-2 control-label" {{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
            'input' => '<div class="col-md-10"><input type="{{type}}" name="{{name}}" {{attrs}} /></div>',
            'select' => '<div class="col-md-10"><select name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}>{{content}}</select></div>',
            'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-group {{required}}" form-type="{{type}}">{{content}}</div>',
            'checkContainer' => '',]
    ]
];
```

Step 2: From your controller inside the method for the correct view call this line.

Don't forget add this on the top of your controller

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;

$this->set('form_templates', Configure::read('Templates'));
```

Step 3: Add this within the bootstrap.php file

```
// Load an environment local configuration file.
// You can use this file to provide local overrides to your
// shared configuration.

Configure::load('templatesConfig','default'); //fixed
```

Step 4(finally): Add this line with the template name you want Bam!.

```
<?php $this->Form->templates($form_templates['shortForm']); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you need all inputs to use a custom markup in a form to show the label after the input (default is before) and a different class for the hardcoded `error-message` for errors:

```
$this->Form->create($entity, ['templates' => [
    'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}',
    'error' => '<div class="error">{{content}}</div>'
]]);
```

If you want to only customize a single input, pass the same 'templates' key to the `FormHelper::input()` options like so:

```
$this->Form->input('fieldname', ['templates' => [
    'formGroup' => '{{input}}{{label}}',
    'error' => '<div class="error">{{content}}</div>'
]]);
```

If you need to define multiple templates and re-use them whenever you want, here's something you can try (mind I am writing it here, never used it before):

```
// in bootstrap (as this is a config i believe
Configure::write('templates', [
    'foo' => [....],
    'bar' => [....]
]);

// in any view
$this->Form->templates(Configure::read('templates.foo'));
$this->Form->create(...);
....
```

You could also create your own helper and define the templates there, etc.

It really all depends on what you want to achieve but that should give you a good understanding of how templates work (not just in forms by the way).

Comment: I tried your last example, but it gives a strange error. As we all are, I am rather novice with Cake 3.0 beta. "Class Configure is not found" confuses me.

Comment: Update: I added use "Cake\Core\Configure;" in my view and everything works great, but I would like to add this to the appropriate file in the hierarchy so that I don't have to add that to every view, unless of course it causes efficacy issues for the entire app as a whole.