# Custom templates using 'radioContainer' in Cakephp 3

Tags: form-helpers, cakephp-3.0

My default radio inputs are like this

```
$this->Form->radio('email_notifications', ['one','two']);
```

I have this in default:

```
<input type="radio" id="usertype-0" value="0" name="userType">
<label for="email-notifications-0">one</label>
```

And need to rephrase this structure to:

```
<label class="radio" for="usertype-0">
    <input type="radio" id="usertype-0" value="0" name="userType">one
</label>
```

Had tried with custom templates. It works fine with 'inputContainer', but not 'radioContainer'. Had used the following to test, by adding a div for radio buttons:
`$this->Form->templates([
       'radioContainer' => '<label {{attrs}}">{{input}}{{text}}</div>'
 ]);`

But nothing work for me as I get only the default structure. Am I doing someway wrong? I tried to  configure with reference to this too: [Cakephp 3 multiple custom template formhelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068782/cakephp-3-multiple-custom-template-formhelpers/26070967#26070967)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what makes you think there would be a template named `radioContainer`, maybe this existed in earlier versions? The radio element related templates are `radio` and `radioWrapper`.

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#list-of-templates** (not completely up to date yet)
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/603f4ee01735f2e8e3c2283540199b4bba70ded7/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L103-L104**

Anyways, the default output looks different to what you are showing, by default radio elements are nested in label elements, ie exactly what you are looking for according to your sample code.

This

```
$this->Form->radio('email_notifications', ['one','two']);
```

will generate the following HTML (indentations and linebreaks added by me)

```
<input type="hidden" name="email_notifications" value="">
<label for="email-notifications-0">
    <input type="radio" name="email_notifications" value="0" id="email-notifications-0">one
</label>
<label for="email-notifications-1">
    <input type="radio" name="email_notifications" value="1" id="email-notifications-1">two
</label>
```

So the fix should be to update to the latest (dev) version.

Comment: I had used the version available [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2014/09/28/cakephp_3_0_0-beta2_released). I should update it?

Comment: Updating to latest dev version, throws error = > Error: Unable to locate widget class "Cake\View\Widget\BasicWidget"

Comment: @G.J I can't help you with that error, at least not without seeing the exact stacktrace and the related code, also this might be something for new question. Please try your form code with a fresh CakePHP installation.

Comment: I fixed this by updating to latest version. Thanks for the shot!